# Error running AsyncTask on main

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class get extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        try {
            URL url  = new URL("http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/IMG_0755-Edit-4.jpg") ;
            URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            image.setImageBitmap(img);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }


}
```

This is my `AsyncTask`, when I try to run this in the Main Thread, the app crashes.

It works fine if I key in

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

However, the whole point of creating the `AsyncTask` was to get rid the need of using that code.

UPDATE: I placed image.setImageBitmap(img) on post execute and it worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: What does the LogCat say on crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot update ui from `doInbackground()`. `doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread. Ui should be updated on the ui thread. `onPostExecute` is invoked on the ui thread. The result of `doInbackground` computation is a parameter to `onPostExecute`. So return result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The check topic under the section The 4 steps in the above link.

```
     image.setImageBitmap(img);
```

You should update ui in `onPostExecute` or use `runOnUiThread`.

But i suggest you update ui in `onPostExecute`.

```
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() //run on ui thread
     {
          public void run() 
          { 
             // update ui       
          }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing an UI operatio in the `doInBackground()` method.

```
image.setImageBitmap(img);
```

You should do this in `onPostExecute()` method.

You should only do the non-UI operations inside `doInBackground()`  method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update your UI in `doInBackground()`, you need to update your UI only in `onPostExecute()`.
So use the following code to update image.

```
public class get extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
Bitmap img;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {
            URL url  = new URL("http://c69282.r82.cf3.rackcdn.com/IMG_0755-Edit-4.jpg") ;
            URLConnection connect = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connect.getInputStream());
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
    {
          image.setImageBitmap(img);
    }


}
```

Also here you have mention anything about variable `image`. You should inflate Imageview in `onPostExecute()` and then add the line for setting image bitmap.